# strange issue with google maps and marker clusterer when zooming in

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I am using google maps api v3 as well as marker cluster plus from this url (http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.9/src/markerclusterer_packed.js)

Now my issue is:

I have two pointers that are mapped to the exact same latitude and longitude. Naturally marker clusterer shows a blue bubble with the number 2 on it. However when I click on the blue bubble the after zooming in, the blue cluser icon dissapears and no pointers are shown.

When this happens my zoomChanged even is also triggered and alerts me that the zoom level is 49 before being triggered again and alerting of the correct zoom level of 20.

Comment: What does _your_ code look like?  Or can you provide link to a jsfiddle (or a live map) that exhibits the issue and instructions on how to reproduce it?

Comment: It's actually a lot of code with multiple layers of polygons but the markers and clustering is pretty standard. I do the standard    mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers); and add pass it the markers. It works perfectly well except when there are two pointers in the same location. IE two markers with the exact same address.

Instead of showing one pointer on top of the other, the cluster icon just disappears once it's clicked on a couple of times.

Comment: Have you tried the [most recent version of MarkerClustererPlus](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/) (looks like 2.0.16 at the present time)?

Comment: unfortunately it's the same issue with 2.0.16

Comment: I zoomed in on a cluster with 2 markers in [this map](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/tanagerproductions_testmapA.html), at 1860 J H O'Bryan Avenue
Grand Rivers, KY 42045 (longitude:-88.237747, latitude:37.006546), it resolves to a marker (there are two markers with the identical information in the KML that is parsed to render the markers), however, it looks like that map uses [MarkerClusterer](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/), not MarkerClustererPlus.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I switched to MarkerClusterer and now clicking on the blue "2" doesn't make it disappear but it still doesn't show the underlying stacked pointers. The blue "2" cluser icons remains unlike your example which works.

Comment: I suggest you investigate the differences between your implementation and mine then.

Comment: Thank you! I compared the two and in my implementation, I wasn't passing options for the clustering  var mcOptions = {gridSize: 80, maxZoom: 15}; now I get the expected behavior

Comment: You may be able to go back to using MarkerClustererPlus as long as you set the maxZoom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the maxZoom so it displays the markers.

from [the documentation](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/blob/master/packages/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html)

```
maxZoom | number | The maximum zoom level at which clustering is enabled or null if clustering is to be enabled at all zoom levels. The default value is null.
```

Comment: updated link to https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/blob/master/packages/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer did not work for me, since our project requires that the marker clusterer is visible at all zoom levels. Using the [Marker Clusterer](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclusterer/) instead of the [Marker Clusterer Plus](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/) plugin fixes the issue, but was not an option due to other factors. What I ended up doing instead was to manually handle the click event after setting the `zoomOnClick` option to `false`:

```
var clusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, [], {
  zoomOnClick: false
});

google.maps.event.addListener(clusterer, 'click', function (cluster) {
  map.panTo(cluster.getCenter());
  map.set('zoom', map.get('zoom') + 2);
});
```